# Process.Modules gives different process name randomly

Tags: .net, process

I was trying to start a process (without its full path) which is present in the %PATH% environment variable, and get its path through the Process Objects Modules Property.

Most of the time it works, but sometime the Modules property contains path of `C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll`

Here is a simple vb.net code to reproduce the issue

```
  Sub checkNtdllError()
        ' Run in a While Loop as this issues is reproduced rarely

        While True
            Dim psi = New ProcessStartInfo
            With psi
                .FileName = "cmd.exe"
                .Arguments = "/c echo 'Hello'"
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .RedirectStandardInput = True
                .CreateNoWindow = True
                .UseShellExecute = False
            End With


            Try
                'Start a new Process of cmd.exe (from the %PATH% environment variable)
                Dim proc = Process.Start(psi)

                Dim moduleName = "Unknown"
                If proc.Modules.Count > 0 Then
                    moduleName = proc.Modules(0).FileName
                Else
                    If Debugger.IsAttached Then Debugger.Break()
                    ' Question: Why proc.Modules.Count was 0?
                    Continue While
                End If

                Console.WriteLine(moduleName) ' This should print the full path of cmd.exe in the console

                If Not moduleName.Contains("cmd") Then
                    ' Question: Why was the ModuleName ntdll.dll?

                    Dim stdOut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
                    Dim stdErr = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd
                    proc.WaitForExit()
                    proc.Dispose()

                    Dim procOut = stdOut & stdErr
                    Console.WriteLine("  " & procOut)
                    ' Observer here that even when the Module Name was not cmd.exe, still the process output was correct
                    If Debugger.IsAttached Then Debugger.Break()
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------")

                End If


            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            End Try

        End While

        Console.Read()
    End Sub
```

**Expectation**
If cmd.exe is found in the path, it should always print the path of cmd.exe in ModuleName

**Questions:**

1. Why is sometimes the proc.Modules array empty?
2. Why is sometimes the proc.Modules array contains path to ntdll.dll?

Comment: FWIW, I can't remember a time when `ntdll.dll` was _not_ there in the list of modules - it's where (part of) the native API is defined.

Comment: The Modules property is a collection of modules. It looks like you may be assuming the first one is always the one you want. You may need to loop through the available modules to check all of them.  Alternatively you may want to try the MainModule property instead. As a side note, you may also be able to use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path") to get the list of paths (semicolon separated) and manually check for the file's location.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError True, ntdll.dll is always there. But why isnt cmd.exe is present?

Comment: @Wiz Yes, i assumed that first module is always the one because MainModule is not always available. I can get my work done by enumerating through the PATH variable. Yet i am a little curious about this case.

Comment: @Wiz, Based on your suggestion, i tried looping through all the modules to find loaded modules other than ntdll.dll, but i found only single entry with ntdll.dll and Main Module was not accessible. See here: https://imgur.com/a/pZ7ppGh

Comment: What is the exception for MainModule - its cut off in the screenshot. I also noticed the process has already exited. Perhaps because it is not running anymore you are getting incomplete results? It may be a speed issue or race condition. The information you are looking for may already be unavailable if the process exits before your code can gather the details. Maybe try running a command that takes longer to complete?